# Authentication errors while using go test

Tags: go

I am using `go test` command after setting `export GO111MODULE=on` to update `go.mod` and run a test suite.

I see so many authentication errors like below

```
The authenticity of host 'gitlab.com (35.231.145.151)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:HbW3g8zUjNSksFbqTiUWPWg2Bq1x8xdGUrliXFzSnUw.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? The authenticity of host 'gitlab.com (35.231.145.151)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:HbW3g8zUjNSksFbqTiUWPWg2Bq1x8xdGUrliXFzSnUw.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? The authenticity of host 'gitlab.com (35.231.145.151)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:HbW3g8zUjNSksFbqTiUWPWg2Bq1x8xdGUrliXFzSnUw.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? The authenticity of host 'gitlab.com (35.231.145.151)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:HbW3g8zUjNSksFbqTiUWPWg2Bq1x8xdGUrliXFzSnUw.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? go: modernc.org/cc@v1.0.0: unknown revision v1.0.0
go: modernc.org/mathutil@v1.0.0: unknown revision v1.0.0
The authenticity of host 'gitlab.com (35.231.145.151)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:HbW3g8zUjNSksFbqTiUWPWg2Bq1x8xdGUrliXFzSnUw.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? go: modernc.org/strutil@v1.0.0: unknown revision v1.0.0
go: modernc.org/golex@v1.0.0: unknown revision v1.0.0
```

go version is `go1.12.1 linux/amd64`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal SSH behavior when it does not know the host keys. The go tooling does not surface the prompt asking you to accept (or reject) the host keys.

You can add them yourself by running:

```
# Fetch keys for gitlab.com, save them to a temporary file.
$ ssh-keyscan -H gitlab.com > tmpkeys
# Print the checksums
$ ssh-keygen -l -f tmpkeys
2048 SHA256:ROQFvPThGrW4RuWLoL9tq9I9zJ42fK4XywyRtbOz/EQ |1|acl3SWCVoYBF6aZrd2FSWIafzT8=|fu8Ivfg6HIGVxsFSx5u3aZwY6CQ= (RSA)
256 SHA256:HbW3g8zUjNSksFbqTiUWPWg2Bq1x8xdGUrliXFzSnUw |1|LMWC/o9XJxW3EtS0hN8/WBBkPrk=|JocpRioPZiOte6ek33XOO6JljQY= (ECDSA)
256 SHA256:eUXGGm1YGsMAS7vkcx6JOJdOGHPem5gQp4taiCfCLB8 |1|BAhrVESJhSsdsGsXHXzY1bvW3P0=|p4KuzvnpUqZA/PGKGkjN0sXKsuk= (ED25519)
# If satisfied with the checksums, append the keys to the known hosts file.
$ cat tmpkeys >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

The host key checksums can be verified on [gitlab's site](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/gitlab_com/#ssh-host-keys-fingerprints).

Once you've done this: try the command again, it should stop prompting you for host keys as they will be known.

Comment: I added those now as mentioned above. Though the prompt is no more seen ,I get ```go: modernc.org/strutil@v1.0.0: unknown revision v1.0.0
go: modernc.org/xc@v1.0.0: unknown revision v1.0.0
go: modernc.org/mathutil@v1.0.0: unknown revision v1.0.0
go: modernc.org/cc@v1.0.0: unknown revision v1.0.0
go: modernc.org/golex@v1.0.0: unknown revision v1.0.0
go: error loading module requirements```

Comment: @ambikanair `modernc.org/mathutil` has no tag v1.0.0?

Comment: I am using `go.mod` and to create a vendor folder I execute `go mod vendor` durin which the above error is seen. So in the `mod` file I have not specified `modernc.org/` anywhere. May be this is indirect dependency